# Get a Big Query script to output a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using the new scripting feature of Big Query to declare a variable and then am using that variable in a standard SQL query.

The structure of the query is :

DECLARE {*name of variable*} {*data type*};

SET {*name of variable*} = {*Value*}'

(A SQL QUERY THEN FOLLOWS USING THE ABOVE VARIABLE)

I understand that this is now a script a no longer a typical query, and thus when I run it, it  runs as a sequence of executable tasks. But is there anyway in the script to explicitly state that I only want to output the resulting table of the SQL query as opposed to both the result of declaring the variable and SQL query?

[What BQ Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DyRk.png)

Comment: Please describe what do you want to achieve. "Seeing only one output" itself is not your goal right?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you "capture" the output, if you are sending a query from Python/Java/CLI, then *the last SELECT statement in script* is the only output that you receive with the API.

Please also note that each "output" that you see come with a cost/bytes-billed, which is another reason for them to be visible at all time.

Update:
If you need to capture the output of SELECT statement to a table, depending on your intention, you may use:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <your_destination_table> AS SELECT ...
```

or

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE <your_destination_table> SELECT ...
```

Comment: Hi Yun, thanks for the reply. So I'm just a data analyst, not a developer. My company uses an in-house tool to schedule big query queries. The error I get from the API is "configuration.query.destinatonTable cannot be set for scripts". So my question is if I can (in the UI console not in a development environment)  set the destination table?

Comment: @BhavikVarsani, I see, updated my answer with how to capture the output of a SELECT from script. Please also notice that you may update multiple tables in one script instead of one table with destination table settings.