# Creating or updating a table from a select statement in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

By using scripting with a variable to optimize data processing for a query [Google BigQuery optimization with subquery in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686016/google-bigquery-optimization-with-subquery-in-where-clause), the ability to specify a destination was lost.

Modeling a solution described in an answer to the question [Get a Big Query script to output a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713210/get-a-big-query-script-to-output-a-table), generates a 'configuration.query.writeDisposition cannot be set for scripts' error.

What are options to address the error, where the data are needed to be written (overwritten) to a table? This is necessary to allow for post-processing and writing (appending) to another table for reporting.

The script is given below.

```
DECLARE start_date STRING;
SET start_date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM `my-project-12345.dataset.my-data-table`);
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `my-project-12345.dataset.my-staging-table`
AS SELECT
  GA.date, 
  GA.field1, 
  hits.field2, 
  hits.field3
FROM 
  `my-project-12345.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS GA, UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
WHERE 
  hits.type IN ('PAGE', 'EVENT')
  AND hits.field0 = 'some value'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > start_date
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20201025'
```

[image: Query settings]

Comment: I just briefly tested  - and it DOES work for me!!! by any chance you have any destination being set in `Query settings` panel?

Comment: Query settings have been added to the question.

Comment: Write preference, which is not visible as a settable parameter without commenting out the script but does show below, is set to "Append to table."

Comment: I think, that is what I was referencing for - so fix this to make sure destination table is not set there! And yes - I am able to reproduce this scenario - so looks like those settings are not automatically disabled for scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that Console UI is reusing whatever settings for Destination was previously used in Query settings panel

[image]

So, looks like you need to make sure you disable Destination

[image]

For this you need to make sure you have any simple query (not a script) so above settings are visible - do needed changes and don't forget to save 'em!

After this done  - your script should go!

Comment: That ultimately worked. I ended up deleting the staging table, commenting out the script elements (to make it just a query again), edited the Query settings to remove its memory of a destination, ran the CREATE OR REPLACE query to create the staging table, restored the script elements, and re-ran it as a script. I wonder if it is also possible that creating the staging table originally as a destination prevented DDL updates to it. Thanks for your help.